# EF6 - One table to hold all contacts against all other tables

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, composite-primary-key

Okay, I know this one is weird, but I'm trying to have all my contacts in one table; each one will relate to another table using that other table's name and an ID within that table. For example, contact **FRED relates to table "Company" with CompanyID 3**, whereas contact **BARNEY relates to table "Accountant" with AccountantID 21**.

```
public class Contact: DbContext
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ReferenceID { get; set; }

    public string ContactName { get; set; }  
}

public class Company: DbContext
{
  [Key]
  public int CompanyID { get; set; }

  public string CompanyName { get; set; }  

  public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class Accountant: DbContext
{
  [Key]
  public int AccountantID { get; set; }

  public string AccountantName { get; set; }  

  public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

So a foreign key won't work, but the composite key (TableName/ReferenceID) will be unique, so the Company can contain a list of associated Contacts (those having a TableName of "Company" and a ReferenceID that matches the CompanyID). It feels like I'll have to set up the modelBuilder something like this, but I'm really not sure how it would work in this particular case...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .WithMany(e => e.Contacts)
            .HasOptional(d => new { "Company", d.ReferenceID } )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

I'm going to call myself an *EntityFrameworkNewbie*, so please forgive any obvious oversights. Thanks.

Comment: Adding tablename as a column is not necessary. Unless you have another reason for utilizing the tablename of the Foreign Table in your column definitions.

Comment: That column tells me to which table the record applies. Each record can be associated to a different table.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. I've seen systems like that before (ok, I wrote one) and it ended up with nothing but problems.

Comment: Just a small note - WillCascadeOnDelete defaults to true anyway so is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something you'll be able to do in EF in the way you're trying to, there are a couple of ways around it, my suggestion would be many to many relationships (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591620.aspx):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>() 
.HasMany(t => t.Contacts) 
.WithMany(t => t.Companies) 
.Map(m => 
{ 
    m.ToTable("CompanyContacts"); 
    m.MapLeftKey("ContactID"); 
    m.MapRightKey("CompanyID"); 
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Accountant>() 
.HasMany(t => t.Contacts) 
.WithMany(t => t.Accountants) 
.Map(m => 
{ 
    m.ToTable("AccountantContacts"); 
    m.MapLeftKey("ContactID"); 
    m.MapRightKey("AccountantID"); 
});
```

etc.

Technically in db terms this means you could have one person be a contact for multiple customers, or a person be a contact for a customer and an accountant at the same time. It's one of these situations where there isn't a correct answer.

Another option would be TablePerType inheritance (so you would create a CompanyContact and an AccountantContact object, both of which inherit from contact (http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

Comment: We actually interview candidates with this question at my company. It's a good one.

Comment: If you desperately want to keep a single table - you could also use TPH, having two nullable IDs (CustomerID and AccountantID) on the contact table and making optional relationships but this is pretty bad database design and can lead to orphaned objects (if both IDs were null) I would definitly recommend one of the other two options.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  This is not a good relational design, and will not give you the referential integrity that is the main benefit of using a relational database in the first place.

If a each related entity can only have one contact, just put the contactId on the related entity.  If the related entity can have more than one contact, create a m:n table that properly represents this (e.g. a CompanyContact table).